# SS2008-Express: Would like to add the database engine to an existing installation

Tags: sql-server-2008

The first time around, I only wanted to upgrade my SQL Server Management Studio from 2005 to 2008. So that's what I did, via the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Now however, I'd like to install a SQL Server 2008 Express **database engine instance**.

How do I do this?

When I reach the 'SQL Server Installation Center', it prompts me for a 'SQL Server 2008 Installation Media' folder. I don't know if I have such a directory, and if I do, I don't know where it lives.

Can anyone help?

P.S.: It should be noted that Microsoft Web Platform Installer insists that SQL Server 2008 Express is installed, even though I know that it is only installed partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the (non-Web Platform) installer and install from there.  It should ask you what features you want to add / change.

[**http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/register/**](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/register/)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the link is outdated. Here is the updated link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B5D1B8C3-FDA5-4508-B0D0-1311D670E336&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [complete list of instructions](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/install-and-configure-sql-server-2008-express) for installing SQL Server 2008 Express.